# EE Paper Savings Bond reads MAIL TO:?

Tags: united-states, bonds, savings

This was issued 23 years ago.

Below my Son's name reads MAIL TO: and gives a person's name and PO Box address. I don't recall how I purchased this, and who this person is, but how does my Son find out if this person is still alive? Can a bank or the treasury direct tell him?

I'd rather he not mail the bond off to someone who may have died, and now someone else uses that PO Box number. He might never get it back.

Comment: why do you need to find that person? you want to return the bonds to them?

Comment: To answer you, in order to cash it, the instructions dictate mailing it off to that person.

Comment: No, in order to cash it take it to a bank.

Comment: Is it possible that the savings bond was a gift from some friend or relative and that the "MAIL TO:" is the person who gave that gift in your son's name?